# Understanding hypothesis testing-compare two series

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value

This is rather simple, but am always confused so perhaps somebody can explain me once for all. 
I have two sets of observations coming from two sources that I want to compare, say $e_1$ and $e_2$ both having $N$ points. Three things could happen:

i) $e_1$ is consistently larger than $e_2$, 
ii) $e_1$ is consistently smaller than $e_2$, 
iii) there is no significant difference between $e_1$ and $e_2$.

I compute the difference in the two series, $e_1 - e_2$, create a test statistic. This could be for example the mean of  $e_1 - e_2$ divided by the standard deviation of  $e_1 - e_2$ (divided by square root of $N$), or it could be another test statistic. If I wanted to do the Diebold-Mariano test it would be another test statistic. But the point is I get some test statistic. I don't know how to interpret this statistic.

I know I need to compare it against say the extreme value of a $T$ distribution or Normal distribution. But know my test statistic could be >1.96, <-1.96, or between -1.96 and 1.96. Help me understand how to interpret the three cases to answer the question- which is consistently larger, $e_1$ or $e_2$.

Comment: This looks like a very generic question on hypothesis testing and it is likely a duplicate of one or more older threads on the topic. Other than the sketch in my answer, I suggest consulting an introductory statistics textbook.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to interpret this statistic.

The test statistic is a summary characteristic of your dataset. It can be treated as a realization from a random variable with a known distribution under a point-valued null hypothesis $H_0$ or a known family of distributions under a set-valued $H_0$. You can evaluate how atypical this realization looks from the perspective of the null distribution(s). Taking the distributions under the alternative hypothesis $H_1$ into consideration, this yields a $p$-value that you can compare to a predetermined significance level $\alpha$ to help you decide between keeping (i.e. not rejecting) $H_0$ or rejecting it in favour of $H_1$.

Alternatively, you can refer to the critical values that again are determined by the distribution(s) under $H_0$ in light of $H_1$. Compare your test statistic to them and see if the statistic is in a critical region (suggesting to reject $H_0$ in favour of $H_1$) or not (suggesting not to reject $H_0$).